# HikariPool-1 - Unusual system clock change detected, soft-evicting connections from pool

Tags: hikaricp

My application use Spring boot and hikaricp.
It occurs this errors:
HikariPool-1 - Unusual system clock change detected, soft-evicting connections from pool

Please help me fix it!

Comment: Unexpected retrograde or prograde clock motion is generally caused by:

 - Computers that drop into power-saving modes.
 - Virtual Machines dependent on container host clock synchronization.

A workaround could be to read data from NTP server.

Answer (score 4):

Two recommendations.  One, make sure you are using the latest version of HikariCP.  Two, configure the computer to sync time from a NTP server.

Newer versions of HikariCP will only evict connections when *backward* time motion is detected.  But will still log a warning for large forward leaps.  Large forward leaps often occur on laptops that go into sleep mode or VMs that are suspended and resumed.