# HikariCP warning message in Play Framework 2.5.x

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.5, hikaricp

I'm getting the message below in Play for Scala, what does this mean and what could be the reason? Is this related to Slick or to JDBC (I'm using both)?

> [warn] c.z.h.p.HikariPool - HikariPool-7 - Unusual system clock change
>   detected, soft-evicting connections from pool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Possible bug in HikariCP**

There was some issues in HikariCP that cause this error:

https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/issues/559

So be sure yo you use 2.4.4 version or newer

**Possible time shifting**

HikariCP will log a warning for large forward leaps. Large forward leaps often occur on laptops that go into sleep mode or VMs that are suspended and resumed.

There is similar question: 
[HikariPool-1 - Unusual system clock change detected, soft-evicting connections from pool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40612380/hikaripool-1-unusual-system-clock-change-detected-soft-evicting-connections-f)

The only thing I would add is that NTP synchronization also could have bugs: [Clock drift even though NTPD running](https://askubuntu.com/questions/26892/clock-drift-even-though-ntpd-running)

Comment: So I shouldn't be getting this warning due to an error in the code? In other words, there's nothing I need to fix in the code to stop this warning?

Comment: Not exactly, it could because of high load, starving resources, and so on. So you can do something. It's not simple "change the line" or "check the box" issue. Read this thread https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/issues/559, there are links to the code, like https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/commit/69dbe20cffd278746a1a43bee92393679d319dce, so you can clearly understand what is going on under the hood.

Comment: I'm getting this warning running scala in a Play application. I use both Slick and JDBC, is this problem related to one of them or could be both?